# Selecting two columns in subquery

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT  Office, 
COUNT(Office) As Tot_Part, 
(SELECT Office, COUNT(Office) 
      FROM trespondent 
      WHERE completion_status= 'Started' 
      OR completion_status = 'Complete' 
      GROUP BY Office ORDER BY Office
) As Total_Resp 
FROM trespondent 
WHERE completion_status <> 'New' 
GROUP BY Office 
ORDER BY Office
```

The issue I am having is the `SELECT` statement in brackets - what I am trying to do is bring back both the `total` people overall and then the `total` people who have Started or Completed.

> 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

If I include  `COUNT(Office)`, then the two columns don't match.

How can I improve my query to achieve the result set I am looking for?

```
Office    Tot   Resp
London    20    2
Leeds     30    17
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any subquery in the select-list has to be a *scalar subquery*, that is it must have one column and one row.

But in this case you don't need a subquery at all:

```
SELECT 
 Office, 
 COUNT(Office) As Tot_Part, 
 SUM(completion_status IN ('Started', 'Complete')) AS Total_Resp
FROM trespondent 
WHERE completion_status <> 'New' 
GROUP BY Office 
ORDER BY Office
```

The trick is that SUM() of values that are 1 or 0 is the same as COUNT() of the rows where the value is 1.  And MySQL treats boolean expressions as 1 or 0.